# Error resolving template [user / registration], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, postman

Проблема с ответами Postman. Ошибка, которая появляется при регистрации пользователя. Понимаю, что суть в том, что он ищет template, но как ему сказать, чтобы этого не делал? Пытался сделать, чтобы метод ничего не возвращал, ошибка всё равно та же?

P.S. Фронт для регистрации не реализовываю.

Код:

```
@PostMapping("/user/registration")
    public User registerNewUserAccount(@RequestBody UserDto accountDto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(accountDto.getFirst_name());
        user.setLastName(accountDto.getLast_name());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));

        user.setEmail(accountDto.getEmail());
        Role role = Role.TENANT;
        user.setRole(role);
        Status status = Status.ACTIVE;
        user.setStatus(status);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Error resolving template [user / registration], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers",
    "path":"/user/registration"
```

[FULL CODE](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/java/task/homerent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна аннотация `@ResponseBody` над методом или всем контроллером (либо использовать `@RestController`), чтобы вернуть конкретно `User` как тело ответа (но
светить в API даже хеши паролей не лучшая идея ;) )

Comment: Правда заработало, спасибо :)  Пока что обучаюсь, приму к сведению. Можете кратко поделиться ссылкой или мнением, как лучше реализовывать подобное? Кажется, я понял, просто сделать void, а возможность отправки объекта убрать, либо же возвращать что-то ещё, кроме User.

Comment: Это слишком широкий вопрос, можно посмотреть https://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security там много вещей затрагивается касательно регистрации пользователей и разные подходы

Comment: Да, знаю этот сайт, с него как раз информацию черпал, позже буду реализовывать оттуда, спасибо за комментарий. Может, подскажете по этой проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182699/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5